# Why do I get "GET" method information when I post a data from IE 11.0 client?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, nanohttpd

I use NanoHTTPD as web server in my Android APP, I submit some date using the function `SubmitCheckedItemsForm()` in client.

In web server client, I can receive "POST" method information when I lanuch the code in both FireFox and Chrome,
but I receive "GET" method  information when I lanuch the code in IE 11.0? Why?

**Server Code**

```
@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
  String uri = session.getUri();
  Method method = session.getMethod();
  Utility.LogError("Method: "+method);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="FormForAction">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function SubmitCheckedItemsForm(action) {

    var mytemp = GetArrayOfCheckedItems();
    var formID = "#FormForAction";

    $(formID).unbind("submit");

    alert(mytemp);

    $(formID).submit(function (eventObj) {

        $(formID).empty(); 

        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
           .attr('name', action)
           .attr('value', JSON.stringify(mytemp))
           .appendTo(formID);
    });

    $(".FilenameCheckboxForSelect").prop("checked", false);

    $(formID).submit();
}
```

**Modified JS**

```
function SubmitCheckedItemsForm(action) {

    var mytemp = GetArrayOfCheckedItems();
    var formID = "#FormForAction";

    $(formID).unbind("submit");

    alert(mytemp);

    $(formID).submit(function (eventObj) {

        $(formID).empty(); 

        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
           .attr('name', action)
           .attr('value', JSON.stringify(mytemp))
           .appendTo(formID);

        $('<div>Body</div>').appendTo(formID);
    });

    $(".FilenameCheckboxForSelect").prop("checked", false);

    $(formID).submit();
}
```

Comment: Can you please share any snapshot of the result?

Comment: Thanks! To Astha Srivastava : I use Utility.LogError("Method: "+method) get result

Comment: I'm sure that I get "GET" method in IE 11.0, and get "POST" method in both Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out this. That when you use the browser to send an HTTP POST request in Internet Explorer 11. When a HTTP POST request is sent without a message body, the GET method is used instead. This is a browser issue. You can check it on the Microsoft support page also. Here: [issue with Form method attribute](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2980014/request-type-is-incorrect-when-browser-uses-a-post-method-to-send-a-http-request-in-internet-explorer-11)

Answer (score 0):

That is not your code problem but the browser's problem. If you want to try you can try this:

There is an option of Enabling/Disabling protected mode in IE and this option is enabled by default for “Internet” zone and “Local Intranet” zone(or any one of them). Disabling at these 2 places may solve the issue.

**Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Internet/Local Intranet -> Uncheck on the "Enable protected mode" option.**
  Just try this if it solves the problem.

Sample code:

```
<form action="your_action_page" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="FormForAction">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I add some  message body in my code to fix the problem ?

Comment: Thanks!  but I still get "GET" method after I add  $('<div>Body</div>').appendTo(formID) in my javascript code. You can checked it at my ASK

Comment: How can I add  "message body" ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get "GET" method after I add  the code  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Bush" />

Comment: It seems that JSON.stringify() can't work well in IE 11.0